# Where do I write code to be called on an update of data used by a Ractive component?

Tags: ractivejs

In the [donut chart](http://examples.ractivejs.org/components) Ractive example, I can update the text below a component graph with:

```
ractive.set('months[0].name', 'Month 1');
```

But if I try and update the data used by the graph with:

```
ractive.set('months[0].data[0].value', 20);
```

nothing happens.

Presumably this is because all that is defined in the JS is an `init` method. What method should I add which will be called on an update of the data? Or do I need to add observers to the data in the `init`? I'd like to add a method to transition/animate between the old data and the new.

I tried a guess at adding an `update` method but that wasn't called.

Comment: Your code was perfect, it's the library that was the problem :( A fix for [this bug](https://github.com/RactiveJS/Ractive/issues/317) introduced a separate issue, which you came across. It's now fixed in the [dev branch](https://github.com/RactiveJS/Ractive/tree/0.4.0/build), so if you can use that you're all set. Thanks for flagging it.

Comment: @RichHarris Thanks very much for the fix, which solved the problem for me. Ractive is a great library, and I've been making good progress developing with it.